# From 2 column to one column layout without using media queries?

Tags: html, css

Initial layout:

[fluid left column] [min-width 300px right column]

Outcome I want when viewport is below 800px:

[100% width left column]

[100% width right column]

Is it possible without using media queries?
Thank you

Comment: You can use bootstrap grid layout for that.

Comment: why no media queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use flex box, there is a really nice implementation here:

[Flexbox Responsive Trick with break points](https://codepen.io/mkstix6/pen/dPmYvV)

Look for this portion of the code. The magic is in flex's flex-grow, shrink, basis

```
.container{
   display:flex;
   flex-wrap:wrap;
}
.fluidWidthDownToAPoint{
  flex-grow:999999; // a relatively big number: needed for OTHER column to 
  be fixed width // if it's too big IE fails to compute
  flex-shrink:1;
  flex-basis:400px; //effectively it's min-width
}
.fixedUnlessOnOwnRow{
 flex-grow:1; // a relatively small number: needed for THIS column to be 
 fixed width
 flex-shrink:1;
 flex-basis:300px; //effectively it's min-width
```

* not my code by the way...belongs to the code pen author.

If not, you can use the "The Fab Four Technique" which is used in a lot of emails that need to be responsive but can't include media queries. The linked article shows step by step how to implement it.

[The Fab Four Technique](https://www.sitepoint.com/responsive-css-patterns-without-media-queries/)